# XSLT replace dot

Tags: xslt

I have to remove dot (.) from data, using translate, I am using XSLT 1.0 and can also use 2.0, I tried using translate and replace in xslt but it only work in other cased like removing space or some char or number, but when I use dot, there is no change.

XML:

```
<Message xmlns:ns1="http://www.Thermofisher.com/Integration/hci/EmployeeBacklog/PayloadToHANA/schema">
  <FSE_BKLOGType xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <Method xmlns:ns1="http://www.Thermofisher.com/Integration/hci/EmployeeBacklog/PayloadToHANA/schema">PUT</Method>
    <FSE_ID>203749</FSE_ID>
    <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
    <T_COUNT>1.032</T_COUNT>
  </FSE_BKLOGType>
  <FSE_BKLOGType xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <Method xmlns:ns1="http://www.Thermofisher.com/Integration/hci/EmployeeBacklog/PayloadToHANA/schema">PUT</Method>
    <FSE_ID>203950</FSE_ID>
    <TICKET_TYPE>T</TICKET_TYPE>
    <T_COUNT>56</T_COUNT>
  </FSE_BKLOGType>
</Message>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <batchParts>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Message/FSE_BKLOGType">
        <batchChangeSet>
          <batchChangeSetPart>
            <method>
              <xsl:value-of select="Method"/>
            </method>
            <FSE_BKLOG>
              <FSE_BKLOGType>
                <FSE_ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="FSE_ID"/>
                </FSE_ID>
                <TICKET_TYPE>
                  <xsl:value-of select="TICKET_TYPE"/>
                </TICKET_TYPE>
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(T_COUNT,' ')">
                <T_COUNT>
                  <xsl:value-of select="translate(T_COUNT,'.','')"/>
                </T_COUNT>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <T_COUNT>
                    <xsl:value-of select="T_COUNT"/>
                    </T_COUNT>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </FSE_BKLOGType>
            </FSE_BKLOG>
          </batchChangeSetPart>
        </batchChangeSet>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </batchParts>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is not removing the dot in <T_COUNT>1.032</T_COUNT>, I want to get like <T_COUNT>1032</T_COUNT>

Thanks
Yatan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test `<xsl:when test="contains(T_COUNT,' ')">` seems not to find any item in your input (`<T_COUNT>1.032</T_COUNT>` doesn't contain a space `' '`), it is not clear what you need it for, the minimal code to simply remove any dot inside of `T_COUNT` would be

```
<xsl:template match="T_COUNT">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '.', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```